# How can I retrieve a list of all scheduled pipelines with their associated pipeline parameters using the azureml python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Using the AzureML python SDK, I can get a list of all scheduled pipelines.

```
Schedule.list(workspace)
```

This returns a list of Schedule objects, with attributes such as their name, recurrence and pipeline_id. The [Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.schedule(class)?view=azure-ml-py) class doesn't seem to have a pipeline_parameters attribute. This is fine for normal pipelines, but I have a parameterised pipeline for which I have scheduled different parameters at different times. How can I know what parameters have been scheduled?

The pipeline_id returned from the Schedule object is for the pipeline endpoint, which is generic and doesn't have the parameters assigned to it.

I'm stumped!